# How to populate a django database with users

Tags: python, json, django

I want to populate a Django database using `manage.py loaddata initial_data.json` where the json file contains the specifications of several objects. My problem is that these object have 'user' attribute referencing to a Django User object, to indicate which user created them. The model for these objects looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MySpecialModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The objects in my json will look like this:

```
[{"fields":{
            "name": "some name",
            "user": XXX
       }
 ...]
```

The problem is that I don't know what to write in place of the XXX to indicate the user. I have tried with user names but Django tells me it expects a number where the XXX are. using a number does not produce any bug but I don't see my database populated. So is there a way to place a Django object in a initial_data.json file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write a `user.pk` there, it is an integer value.

```
[{"fields":{
            "name": "some name",
            "user": 1
       }
 ...]
```

Obviously, the user with that pk should be created before you import any object with foreign key to it, so maybe it is easier to create some (fake or not) users through admin before and export they with: `python manage.py dumpdata auth.User --indent 4 > users.json`

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way at all to get the user by username I guess. That should do the trick anyway.

Comment: @Zulko also read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#natural-keys